# CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to sign APK package

Tags: java, unity-game-engine, sdk, keystore

stderr[
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
]
stdout[
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Users\asjkluyel\Desktop\android-sdk-windows\build-tools\26.0.2\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
]

jdk 9.0.1

sdk 26.0.2

_JAVA_OPTIONS
-Xmx512M

JAVA_HOME 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.1

[image: apksigner log]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue when running `apksigner.bat` using a Java 9 runtime. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71382297. A fix should be available in Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.4 or newer. Until then, the workaround is to remove `-Djava.ext.dirs="%frameworkdir%"` from `apksigner.bat`. See https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/tools/apksig/+/578611. Another workaround is to switch to a Java 8 runtime.